# Firebase Verify Id Token but the client not ready yet so I don't know data contain from client

Tags: android, firebase, spring-boot, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have an app built using java spring-boot, and for authentication, I want to use Google Sign In, I use Firebase Admin SDK ([Verify Id Token)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens) for authenticating the user token that retrieves from the client(Android). 
This is my code for authentication

```
FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(idToken);
String uid = decodedToken.getUid();
```

*idToken* comes from the client, but the android apk is not ready yet so I don't know exactly how the data format and content.

**Anyone who knows or has an experience in this that I wish want to share?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a way to test the above code, see how we obtain ID tokens in our automated integration tests: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/blob/master/src/test/java/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthIT.java#L460